# How to make AWK use a variable created in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have script that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#exampel inputfile is "myfile.txt"
inputfile=$1
basen=`basename $inputfile .txt`  # create basename

cat $inputfile | 
awk '{print $basen "\t" $3}  # this doesn't print "myfile" but the whole content of it.
```

What I want to do above is to print out in AWK the variable called 'basen' created before.
But somehow it failed to do what I hoped it will.

So for example `myfile.txt` contain these lines

```
foo bar bax
foo qux bar
```

With the above bash script I hope to get

```
myfile bax
myfile bar
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: @tripleee How can this post be a duplicate? This is posted 7 years before and your suggested post 4 years ago.

Comment: Yours is a common FAQ.  Question age is not an important consideration when sorting duplicates.  See also e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate/252930#252930

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use it like this.

```
for i in `find $1 -name \*.jar`
do
jar tvf $i| awk -F '/' '/class/{print "'${i}'" " " $NF }' >> $classFile
done
```

You should use

> "'${i}'"

in AWK to use the

> $i

created in Bash Script.

Comment: use `$()` instead of backticks. And `find` with `for` loop like that will break on files with spaces. Quote your `$1` variable

Answer (score 29):

The `-v` flag is for setting variables from the command line.  Try something like this:

```
awk -v "BASEN=$basen" '{print BASEN "\t" $3}'
```

Comment: +1 This is the best way to inject a variable as it will work even if `$basen` contains special characters like apostrophes, quotes, or spaces.

Answer (score 4):

you can just do everything in awk

```
awk '{gsub(".txt","",ARGV[1]);print ARGV[1] "\t" $3}' inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you run awk **as the sub process of the shell you declared the vars**
Within the shell

```
export MY_VARS="whatever"; #// IT NEEDS to be exported, to allow the sub process awk read access.
echo ""| awk '{
    print "Reading values from within awk : "ENVIRON["MY_VARS"];
}'
```

Result:

> Reading values from within awk : whatever

notice the importance of **export**. With out it, the vars from the shell is considered
local and does not get passed to the co-processes.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that bash variables (environment variables) are not expanded within single-quoted strings. Try replacing

```
'{print $basen "\t" $3}'
```

with

```
"{print \"$basen\" \"\t\" \$3}"
```

Comment: there is a gem right there :) thank you DavidZ !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make an awk variable. `awk -v awkvar=$bashvar 'awkscript'`.

Comment: you will need to put `awkvar=$bashvar` under doublequotes, otherwise it will have problems with bashvariables with spaces in it: `awk -v "awkvar=$bashvar" 'awkscript'`